# Any idea why my Github Pages site isn't showing? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

here's the link to my GH page

https://filipdimko11.github.io/crypto-tracker/

When running it locally, the project renders everything. After hosting it on GH pages, though, the website doesn't render anything (no errors in the console either).

I tried making an empty commit, saw it as another solution on StackOverflow, but that didn't fix it. Using ReactJS, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because in your `index.html` file you are referencing your assets like `/static/js/main.2227a53b.js` which makes sense when you are running locally.

But when you deploy to github pages, the directory structure is different. To make it work properly you'd need the routes to be prefixed with `crypto-tracker/` For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="Your best crypto tracker!" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>Crypto Tracker</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="crypto-tracker/static/js/main.2227a53b.js"></script>
    <link href="crypto-tracker/static/css/main.f53fb378.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on what build tool you are using, this is probably configurable.